# Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Child: Name>]>": "Mark.MarkOwner" must be a "Child" instance

Tags: python, django

This is another dumb question. I'm really new at django and I don't know what I need to do. Can someone please help me? Or send some pages of documentation? The goal is to make mark selector assigned to child that it displays for. There is some of my code.

> My HTML

```
{% if child %}
  {% for c in child  %}
  <tr>
  <th>
  {{c.ChildName}}<br>
  </th>
  <th>
    <form action="{% url 'marks:addmark' class.id sc.id %}" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
              <select required name="sub">
                      <option value=1>1</option>
                      <option value=2>2</option>
                      <option value=3>3</option>
                      <option value=4>4</option>
                      <option value=5>5</option>
                      <option value=6>6</option>
                      <option value=7>7</option>
                      <option value=8>8</option>
                      <option value=9>9</option>
                      <option value=10>10</option>
                      <option value=11>11</option>
                      <option value=12>12</option>
              </select>
              <button type="submit">готово</button>
              </form>
  </th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

> views.py

```
def mlat(request, classid, subjectid):
    a = Class.objects.get( id = classid )
    b = SubjectClas.objects.get( id = subjectid )
    d = Child.objects.filter(ChildClass = a)
    c = Mark.objects.filter(MarkSubjet = b)
    return render(request, 'marks/mlat.html', {'class':a, 'sc':b, 'subjectsyes':c, 'child':d})
def addmark(request, classid, subjectid):
    a = Class.objects.get( id = classid )
    b = SubjectClas.objects.get( id = subjectid )
    d = Child.objects.filter(ChildClass = a)
    c = Mark.objects.filter(MarkSubjet = b)
    Mark.objects.create(Markd = request.POST['sub'], MarkSubjet = a, MarkOwner = d)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('marks:mlat', args=[b.id, a.id,]))
```

> models.py

```
class SubjectClas(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField('Предмет', max_length = 50, default='Алгебра')
    clas = models.ForeignKey(Class, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
class Child(models.Model):
    ChildName = models.CharField('Имя ученика', max_length = 50)
    ChildClass = models.ForeignKey(Class, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ChildName
class Mark(models.Model):
    MarkOwner = models.ForeignKey(Child, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    MarkSubjet = models.ForeignKey(SubjectClas, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    Markd = models.CharField('Оценка', max_length = 2)
    MarkDate = models.DateField('Дата')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Markd
```

> urls.py

```
    path('<int:classid>/<int:subjectid>/', views.mlat, name = 'mlat'),
    path('<int:classid>/<int:subjectid>/addmark/', views.addmark, name = 'addmark')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is coming from your:
`d = Child.objects.filter(ChildClass = a)`
.filter returns a queryset and you cannot assign a queryset to Mark.MarkOwner.

change it to:

```
d = Child.objects.get(ChildClass = a)
```

to return a Child instance.

But if the Child does not exist this will return an error so I recommend using:

```
if Child.objects.filter(ChildClass = a).exists():
    d = Child.objects.get(ChildClass = a)
```

This way you can handle the case where Child does not exist without crashing